# A better way to assign value for R object?

Tags: r

I want to randomly draw one of the obejct from (a,b,c), the probability vector is (pro_a, pro_b, pro_c) and pro_a+ pro_b+pro_c=1. The extracted object is assigned a value of 1, and the remaing are assigned a value of 0. Using the sample function and if statement, I have the following R code. How can I make the code more simple.

```
ev=sample(c("a","b","c"),1,c(0.2,0.3,0.5),replace=TRUE)
ev
a=0
b=0
c=0
if(ev=="a"){a=1}
if(ev=="b"){b=1}
if(ev=="c"){c=1}
a
b
c
```

Comment: Do `a`, `b` and `c` really need to be separate variables in your environment? What exactly do you do with these values after you set them? If they are always a triplet of values, it would be much easier just to keep them as a named vector or something.

Comment: They can be kept as a named vector.

Answer (score 2):

Use a named vector:

```
choices = rep(0, 3)
names(choices) = c("a", "b", "c")

ev = sample(names(choices), size = 1, prob = c(0.2, 0.3, 0.5))
# (replace = TRUE is pointless when only drawing a sample of size 1)

choices[ev] = 1
choices
# a b c 
# 0 0 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Storing it into a list, which you can then put into global env

```
vec=c("a","b","c")
pro=c(0.2,0.3,0.5)

ran=sample(vec,1,pro,replace=T)

setNames(
  split((vec==ran)*1L,1:length(vec)),
  vec
)

$a
[1] 0

$b
[1] 1

$c
[1] 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the old-fashioned switch statement to generate a named vector:

```
 switch(sample(1:3, 1, prob=c(0.2,0.3,0.5)),
        "1" = c(a=1, b=0, c=0),
        "2" = c(a=0, b=1, c=0),
        "3" = c(a=0, b=0, c=1))
```

Comment: Fine for 3, but this becomes increasingly painful for every additional choice. And plenty of typo potential.

Comment: Agree. Just works nicely for this use case.